# 404 error - cannot connect to server from emulator

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, emulation, ionic-framework

I am trying to connect to my server from my emulator and it gives 404 error. I also tries to connect to my localhost with 10.0.2.2 and it still gives same 404 error. Following are the details of http call made from emulator I collected from chrome browser debugger network tab

```
Request URL:http://ec2-52-27-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:1337/auth/local
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found (from cache)
Request Headers
 Provisional headers are shown
 Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
 Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Origin:file://
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; Android SDK built for x86 Build/LKY45) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/39.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
Request Payloadview source
 {email: "tt"}
 email: "tt"
Response Headers
 Client-Via:shouldInterceptRequest
```

My android application is in ionic framework based on phonegap and angularjs.

Comment: try with your system ip

Comment: I did that with no change